# How to enable sticky keys on a Mac

Tags: keyboard

I've seen this option in one Ubuntu machine and I want to replicate it in my mac:

Hold a Key for 2 second to activate it.

What I have seen is this:
Hold down a Key for 2 second (<kbd>Shift</kbd> for example).
Then write something and the written text was as if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed (and it acts like the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> pressed).
Then the key is pressed one time to deactivate it.

Is it possible to achieve this on a mac too?

Comment: For the Shift button behaviour you describe you can also just press Caps Lock.

Comment: yes, of coursethe question is more general

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is called sticky keys.
You can activate as follows on a Mac:

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Type in `sticky` in the search bar and hit enter.
3. Tick `Enable sticky keys`.

OR

1. Open System Preferences.
2. Go to `Accessibility`.
3. Go to `Keyboard`.
4. Tick `Enable sticky keys`.

[image: Sticky Keys option screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

One problem with sticky keys is that there is a short delay before sticky keys get registered. If for example you press shift and z immediately after it, z is not capitalized. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/522239/lag-in-sticky-keys-for-mac).

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) has its own implementation of sticky keys which doesn't have that issue.